# html, css, sticky box, troubles with Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a sticky box on this page http://www.uclock.it/CreateClock/

If you add some more rows and scroll the small clock preview should always stays visible on the screen and between the first and last row.

The problem is, it works somehow in FF, IE (sort of) and definitely doesn't work in Chrome.

I cannot figure out what the problem is.

I have fiddle which simulates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rRh8F/3/

The css is:

```
.smallClockPreview
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 237px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    margin-top: -74px;
    width: 237px;
    position:relative;
}
.smallClockPreviewFixed
{
     display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 237px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    margin-top: -217px;
    width: 237px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

and the js is (sorry the variables are in Czech):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if ($('#smallClockPreview').length) { 
    var maleHodinyTop = $('#smallClockPreview').offset().top; 
    var maleHodinyVyska = $('#smallClockPreview').height(); 
    $(window).scroll(function (evt) {
        var zarazka = $('.clearHelp').offset().top; 
        var zarazkaMinusVyska = zarazka - $('#smallClockPreview').outerHeight(); 
        var topOknaOdZacatku = $(this).scrollTop(); 
        if (topOknaOdZacatku > maleHodinyTop) {
            if (topOknaOdZacatku < zarazkaMinusVyska) {
                $('#smallClockPreview').removeAttr('style');                     $('#smallClockPreview').addClass('smallClockPreviewFixed').removeAttr('style'); 
            } else {
                if (topOknaOdZacatku > zarazka) {
                }
                else {
                    if ((zarazka - maleHodinyVyska) > maleHodinyVyska) {
                        $('#smallClockPreview').css({ "position": "relative", "top": (zarazka - maleHodinyVyska) }); 
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $('#smallClockPreview').removeAttr('style');
            $('#smallClockPreview').removeClass('smallClockPreviewFixed'); 
        }
    });
}
});
```

Thank you very much for any help

Regards
Petr

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.removeAttr('style')`, just use `.css({'position':'fixed','right':'0');`. `Fixed` and `absolute` ignore `float` by default, so just assign their spacing with `right`. I've u[pdated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRh8F/5/) to demonstrate that it works. This will also give you the opportunity to simplify your javascript and css.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to specify `right` and `top` for the `position: fixed` to work properly, check the new version of this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rRh8F/6/

I added:

```
top: 0;
right: 10px;
```

to your `.smallClockPreviewFixed` class; also you may remove `float: right;`; `float` will not do you any good when it comes to `fixed` elements since they are out of the flow anyway;